# Anchor to a view nested inside of multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I have a view hierarch that looks like this:

```
ConstraintLayout
    ViewNumberOne
    FragmentContainerViewA
        FragmentContainerViewB
            ViewNumberTwo
```

The fragment that occupies `FragmentContainerViewA` is added in programatically. How do I anchor `ViewNumberOne` to `ViewNumberTwo` with this setup? I've been experimenting with putting a `FragmentContainerViewB.getViewNumberTwoId` and anchoring to that id within the constraint layout, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.